# Compare Multiple Ranges and Return Non-Overlapping Sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have ranges of numbers and I need to return the sets that do not overlap with one another For example, here is a set of numbers:

```
1,4
0,3
4,7
0,4
```

I need to return:

```
0,3
4,7
```

An example of a larger data set:

```
0,1
0,2
2,5
4,8
3,7
8,11
8,9
9,11
```

I would need to return:

```
0,2 
3,7 
8,11
```

It would need to account for situations where if a smaller set is in another and should be discarded. Using the previous set,

```
0,1
0,2
3,7
```

Since 0,1 is contained within 0,2 set 0,1 should be discarded.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks much.

Comment: What do you mean 'contained within'?

Comment: if one range is 0-2 [0,1,2] and the other range is 0-1 [0,1], 1 is between 0-2 and therefore 0,1 should be discarded. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to find the largest set of non-overlapping sets you should check [Interval scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling#Greedy_polynomial_solution) problem, especially solution using greedy algorithm. If performance doesn't matter you can try playing with python [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) union or subset and compare sets with each other.

```
set(range(0, 4)).union(set(range(0, 1)))
```

Comment: The goal is to find the largest non-overlapping sets within a group that would sit next to each other. For example, 0,4 and 5,8 and 9,11 so that set 3,10 would be discarded.

Comment: You might want to play with recursive functions to find ones that sit next to each other. Not sure quite how to do it though.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to interval scheduling. It is what I was looking for, I was able to modify the following code to get the result needed: 

https://github.com/farazdagi/algorithms/blob/master/weighted-interval-scheduling.py